# Using OAuth authentication on Android for AppEngine authentication

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication

There is a lot of information but I can't find an up-to-date answer for my question.

**I've got**
1) Android app where user has got auth token (say from GoogleAuthUtil)
2) Google AppEngine app which provides custom REST API

**Question**
Is there any way to use token (got on Android side) to authenticate against AppEngine application? 
 On the AppEngine side I just need to verify e-mail of the user

**P.S.**
 I don't want to use Endpoints since they don't support custom domains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will be interested - here is the result of my research on what is the best way to authenticate against AppEngine app

I ended up with solution described in this [brilliant article](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) by [@Tim Bray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539321/tim-bray).

The solution has following advantages:
1) It works for local testing
2) There is no limitations on domain (Endpoints don't support custom domains)
3) If you have custom REST API you just need to add token verification (other code stays as it is)
4) It utilizes Google OAuth mechanism implementation, so I consider it as one of recommended methods
5) It's really easy to implement

Comment: Hi @sberezin I tried following that guide but it didn't work for me, I get an "Unknown" error when trying to get the token, could you share your code here so I (and anyone else who is having this issue) can take a look? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I used the same code as in @Tim Bray's article. What line is error exaclty on? Or do you mean you get an error in Android when calling to GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()?

Comment: yeah I got an error when calling GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(), in the end we decided to go with another scope that didn't include the app engine and it worked fine. Thanks anyway.